# JPA Remove . What is the recommended way to do it in this case?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

This question is killing me guys:

so lets say this very simple case:

(spring/Hibernate/jpa2/@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION))

We have DAO entities:

```
class User{
private Set<Car> carSet;
... usual setters + getters
}

class Car{
private User user;
... usual setters + getters

}
```

which of the following is the the recommended way to delete a car by carId and why (this will be done in a http post request, no other operation will be done besides this remove)?

1 ) Simple remove operation;

```
Car  car = dao.find(Car.class, carId);
dao.remove(car);
```

2) Clean references first. When is this method recommended?

```
Car  car = dao.find(Car.class, carId);
car.getUser().getCarSet().remove(car); // this one as far as I know will usually fetch the other cars, and I think is not optimal, am I right?
car.setUser(null);
dao.remove(car);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you should just remove car, unless you need your User.getCarSet() updated before the end of transaction.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Car is pointing to User, in other words, Car has a foreign key property pointing to User.  Therefore removing Car will also remove the reference to User.  This will also remove Car from the User's Car Set.  So, option 1 is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it depends on the owning side of the relationship.

To simplify it, let's assume a dummy rule: The owning side is always the one with the foreign key (for the whole story I would recommend a good book such as [Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java™ Persistence API](http://www.apress.com/9781430219569)). Since you have a `@ManyToOne` relationship from `Car` to `User`, by our dummy rule, `Car` is the owning side:

```
   *---------------*       *--------------*     
   |      CAR      |       |     USER     |     
   *---------------*       *--------------*     
   |  CARD_ID (PK) |   ~-> | USER_ID (PK) |     
   |  USER_ID (FK) | --~   *--------------*     
   *---------------*
```

When you are removing the owning side, nothing else must be done.

In your case, since car is the owning side you can simply remove the car, i.e, `dao.remove(car);` will suffice.

Now let's think about the opposite situation. Let's say that you needed to remove a `User`, i.e., the referenced side.

If you remove a user that have a car associated with it (assuming no cascading behavior is in place), the database `DELETE` operation would fail because of a FK Violation.

The rule of tumb is: **Relationship maintenance is responsibility of the application**. Which means adjusting the reference on the opposite (owning) side of the relationship.

If the foreign key column in the car table can be `NULL` you could use `car.setUser(null);` before removing the user. This would leave an orphan car in your database.

If the foreign key column is `NOT NULL`, before removing the user you need either to associate the car with another user:

```
   car.setUser(anotherUser);
```

Or remove the car from the database all together:

```
   dao.remove(car);
```

As I said, there is much more to relationship maintenance than that. JPA have features such as `@CascadeType`s; bidirectional `@ManyToMany` relationships where the owning side can be chosen arbitrarily; unidirectional `@OneToMany`(with a join table) etc. But I think this pretty much sums up the basics.